# How can I make my jQuery plugin code prettier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've written my **first** jQuery plugin and it goes a little something like this.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.MyFancyPlugin= function (settings) { 

        var defaults = {
            someSetting = 'default for some setting'
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);

        function foo(){
            // do stuff
        };

        function bar(){
            // do stuff
        };

        return this.each(function (){
            // do more stuff
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The plugin works just fine, but I'm so freaking anal about the looks that I hate the way the functions are nested.

My "preference" for the look of my JS is something like this.

```
MyNamespace.Class1 = {

    foo: 'foo',

    bar: function() {
        return 'bar';
    }
};
```

But I can't seem to wrap my head around this when making a jQuery plugin. Can someone lend a hand? I'm most concerned about the `var`'s and the fact that they're private.

On a side note, I'd like to know what the "official" names are for each of these approaches to structuring JavaScript.

Comment: Should be moved to Codereview

Comment: I find the above pretty pretty ;)

Comment: @KyleMacey, I suppose it "could" go to code review, but I'm not looking to have it reviewed... see, what I posted would be reviewed as "DOES NOT WORK". I'm trying to learn the differences between the two approaches to structuring JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing at all wrong with your first example, which is loosely the "module" pattern, except it may be duplicating the functions unnecessarily. Your latter example is just how you assign anonymous functions to properties on an object, which is inappropriate if the functions in question don't need to be properties of the object.

Limiting the scope of functions by wrapping them in other functions is a fundamental JavaScript idiom, not ugly at all.

However, if `foo` and `bar` don't need access to the variables and arguments in scope when your plug-in function is called (and if `defaults` is really static), you can move them out a level so they're not recreated every time your plug-in is called:

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        someSetting: 'default for some setting'
    };

    function foo(){
        // do stuff
    };

    function bar(){
        // do stuff
    };

    $.fn.MyFancyPlugin= function (settings) { 

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);

        return this.each(function (){
            // do more stuff
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Also note that I corrected the syntax of your `defaults` initializer (`:`, not `=`).

---

Side note: Since your plug-in function isn't a *constructor* function, the overwhelming convention in the JavaScript world is to use camelCasing with an initial lower case letter (e.g., `myFancyPlugin` rather than `MyFancyPlugin`).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. Can you point me to a little more info on "anonymous functions" versus the "module pattern"?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: It's not really an either/or, but fundamentally the module pattern is nothing more than having an outer scoping function that contains anything you want to keep private, and exports anything you want to make public. Your first example (and my recasting of it) both do that. The problem with just dumping everything on an object in an object initializer is that *everything* is then public on that object.

Comment: +1, +Accepted - Perfect, exactly what I needed to know. You're a champ.

Comment: Also, I found a little more info over at GitHub on how to structure the jQuery Plugins. https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns